# View saved wifi passwords using terminal

Tags: password

How can I view the wifi password of networks I'm already connected to in the terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `nmcli dev[ice]` command:

```
nmcli dev wifi show-password
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I can do

```
cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
ls -a
```

to view what Wifi configs are saved. Then, I can do `sudo cat <wifiName>` where `<wifiName>` is the wifi I want to see the password of.

In the output, there is a field called `psk` which is the password.